# Class c++ has no member named

Tags: c++, classes, vector

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de uma lista de lista para representar um grafo em memória.

Fiz apenas essa primeira parte e estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

```
class std::vector<No> has no member named 'getId'
```

Segue meu código até o momento...

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

no.h:

```
#ifndef NO_H_INCLUDED
#define NO_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include "Aresta.h"

using namespace std;

class No{
    private:
        int id;
        vector<Aresta> *adjNo;
    public:
        No(int id);
        int getId();
        vector<Aresta>* getAdjNo();
        void inserirAdj(Aresta aresta);
        int totalAdjacencias();
};

#endif // NO_H_INCLUDED
```

no.cpp:

```
#include "No.h"
#include <vector>

No::No(int id){
    this->id=id;
    this->adjNo = new vector<Aresta>;
}

int No::getId(){
    return this->id;
}

vector<Aresta>* No::getAdjNo(){
    return this->adjNo;
}

void No::inserirAdj(Aresta aresta){
    adjNo->push_back(aresta);
}

int No::totalAdjacencias(){
    this->adjNo->size();
}
```

Aresta.h:

```
#ifndef ARESTA_H_INCLUDED
#define ARESTA_H_INCLUDED

class Aresta{
    private:
        int id;
        int peso;

    public:
        Aresta(int id, int peso);
        int getId();
};

#endif // ARESTA_H_INCLUDED
```

aresta.cpp:

```
#include "Aresta.h"

Aresta::Aresta(int id, int peso){
    this->id=id;
    this->peso=peso;
}

int Aresta::getId(){
    return this->id;
}
```

Grafo.h:

```
#ifndef GRAFO_H_INCLUDED
#define GRAFO_H_INCLUDED

#include "No.h"

using namespace std;

class Grafo{
    private:
        vector<No> *listNos;
    public:
        Grafo();
        void addNo(int id);
        bool existeNo(int id);
};

#endif // GRAFO_H_INCLUDED
```

grafo.cpp:

```
#include "Grafo.h"
#include <iostream>

Grafo::Grafo(){
    listNos = new vector<No>;
}

void Grafo::addNo(int id){
    if(!existeNo(id)){
        No noAux(id);
        listNos->push_back(noAux);
    } else
        cout << "No ja existe no Grafo";
}

bool Grafo::existeNo(int id){
    for(int i=0; i < listNos->size(); i++){
        if(listNos[i].getId() == id)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Em que linha do código ocorre o erro?

Comment: É na linha que tem `if(listNos[i].getId() == id)`? Por que `listNos` é um *ponteiro* para um vetor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, você não respondeu aos meus questionamentos, mas considerando a mensagem de erro ("class std::vector has no member named 'getId'"), o erro quase certamente ocorre na linha que contém essa chamada de código (dentro da função `Grafo::existeNo()`):

```
. . .
if(listNos[i].getId() == id)
. . .
```

Verificando a definição de `listNos[i]`, se observa que ele é declarado assim:

```
. . .
vector<No> *listNos;
. . .
```

Ou seja, você está declarando um ponteiro para *um vetor* da biblioteca padrão (isto é, um `std::vector`), que contém instâncias estáticas da classe `No`. Assim, o erro se deve ao fato de que `listNos` é um ponteiro, e não uma classe estaticamente alocada.

Considere esse exemplo didático:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Este é um vetor de inteiros, alocado estaticamente
    vector<int> vPares;

    // Este é um vetor de inteiros, alocado dinâmicamente
    vector<int> *vImpares;
    vImpares = new vector<int>();

    // Insere números nos vetores
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        if(!(i % 2))
            vPares.push_back(i);
        else
            vImpares->push_back(i);
    }

    // Imprime o conteúdo dos vetores:
    cout << "Numeros pares: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vPares.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vPares[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Numeros impares: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vImpares->size(); i++)
    {
        cout << (*vImpares)[i] << " ";
        //cout << vImpares->at(i) << " "; // <= ALTERNATIVA SEM PRECISAR DO *
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Como vImpares foi alocado dinâmicamente, precisa ser desalocado!
    delete vImpares;

    return 0;
}
```

Cuja saída é essa:

```
Numeros pares: 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
Numeros impares: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Você vai perceber que se você aloca dinamicamente usando um ponteiro, você precisa referenciar como um ponteiro (adicionando o `*`) *antes* de usar normalmente. No seu caso, basta usar:

```
(*listNos[i]).getId()
```

ou, alternativamente (tal como no exemplo didático anterior):

```
listNos->at(i).getId()
```

Só pra completar a informação, se você utilizar um iterador (*iterator*), talvez fique mais fácil. No meu exemplo:

```
. . .
cout << "Numeros impares: ";
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vImpares->begin(); it != vImpares->end(); ++it)
{
    cout << *it << " ";
}
cout << endl;
. . .
```

No seu caso:

```
. . .
for (vector<No>::iterator no = listNos->begin(); no != listNos->end(); ++no)
{
    no->getId()
. . .
```

Comment: Extremamente perfeita a sua resposta @Luiz Vieira, eu não pude responder antes aos seus questionamentos pois estava viajando.
Mais uma coisa, no contexto do seu exemplo didático, como faço para remover o item 7 por exemplo, utilizando ponteiros...

Comment: Obrigado Dudu. Vc faz a remoção normalmente. O fato de ter um ponteiro para um vetor só faz vc precisar acessar seus métodos/atributos por meio do operador `->` ao invés do operador `.`. Pra remover pelo índice use [`std::vector::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) e pra remover pelo valor use *também* [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: Entao se eu fizer std::remove(no->getId()) vai remover o elemento que tem o no com esse id passado como parâmetro?

Comment: Não. Conforme a documentação no link que eu te passei indica (você leu?), você precisa passar também o iterator inicial e final (algo como `std::remove(listNos->begin(), listNos->end(), no);`. Mas, o que o seu vetor armazena não são ids numéricos, e sim instâncias estáticas de `No`. Logo, vc precisa passar o iterador do nó, e não o id dele. Pra funcionar do jeito que vc quer, vc precisa implementar um operador de comparação que, ai sim, vai comparar pelo ID. Sugiro que abra uma nova pergunta. Este site não é um fórum. :)